# Get origin database from mysql view

Tags: mysql, database, view

I would like to get the view origin database from where the view is added in another database.

Example:

db_1 -> table_1

db_2 -> table_2

db_3 -> view_1 && view_2

I want to know with a mysql sentence the db that view_1 or view_2 belongs to.

Comment: Are you aware of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-views-table.html ?

Comment: Or are you wondering about the base table that the view references? Then you need https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-view-table-usage-table.html which is a new info table in MySQL 8.0.13 and later.

Comment: @BillKarwin, the second one, the problem is that I am using mysql 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE view is new in MySQL 8.0.13. If you use an older version of MySQL (or any version of MariaDB), there is no such information_schema table, so you can't get this information by any query.

You need to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 to get this feature in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

I understand from the comments above that you are using MySQL 5.7. In MySQL 5.7, you would need to come up with a way to parse the view definition, which you can read from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS. This is a complex task because a view can have a wide variety of SELECT syntax. A view can reference multiple tables, using joins, subqueries, or unions. It can even reference no table.

Comment: Indeed, as you mention I would have to upgrade mysql but unfortunately that`s not for me to decide.So, what I did was exactly what you mention, parse the view definition, since I only need the database origin name I was able to. But like you say, best practice would be to upgrade mysql.